# Is there any way to force the use of a class and not a subclass in a method?

Tags: swift

I have a parent class called BasicUser and a subclass called User that inherits from BasicUser. When I try to add a basic user(BasicUser class) using a user(User class) it passes the whole User object instead of just the BasicUser.

Is there a way to avoid sending a subclass that conforms to a class in a method?

```
class BasicUser {}

class User: BasicUser {}

func addAttendingUser(_ newUser: BasicUser) {

}

let user = User()
addAttendingUser(user)
```

EDIT:
Some logic behind ObjectMapper.
First of all, it maps a Festival and because Festival has a BasicUser array (attendingUsers) it calls mapping on BasicUser which it's a User.

User has a followedFestivals array and this is where it gets accessed from multiple threads.

On User class:

```
override func mapping(map: Map) {
    super.mapping(map: map)
    followedFestivals <- map["followed_festivals"]
}
```

On Festival class:

```
override func mapping(map: Map) {
    super.mapping(map: map)
    attendingUsers <- map["attending_users_list"]
}
```

Comment: Why is passing the whole `User` not desirable?

Comment: I'm using ObjectMapper to encode the user and some of the properties of the User class are accessed from another thread while creating a BasicUser. On addAttendingUser method, when you check newUser, you can see that it's a User class but I want to force it to be a BasicUser without doing some logic and create a new BasicUser.

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible, you should manually handling the convertion from `User` to `BasicUser`; btw it sounds that you're doing something wrong if you need this...

Comment: One of the key points of Inheritance is : Children classes can be used as Parent Classes. Maybe `User` should not actually be a subclass of `BasicUser`. Kindly show `addAttentingUser` logic

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio How would you achieve something similar to this? Extending a class would have the same problem?

Comment: @JoshuaFrancisRoman If you want I can show it but it's crashing from another side as the main problem is that the type is User instead of BasicUser.

Comment: You can check the type isn't `User` in `addAttendingUser` method

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing would be instantiate a new object.

```
class BasicUser {

    init() {}

    init(fromOther other: BasicUser) {
        // basically copy the value from other to self
    }

}

class User: BasicUser {}

func addAttendingUser(_ newUser: BasicUser) {
    let newUser = BasicUser(fromOther: newUser)
    // do your stuff
}

let user = User()
addAttendingUser(user)
```

Comment: Thanks!! This is what I'm doing, but I thought that it could be a better way to solve this.

Comment: Maybe there's some code that you can change elsewhere but you're stuck on this; post what you do with `ObjectMapper` and what is done in the other thread

Comment: Okay! I've updated the question to help clarify the usage.